# Left_join from a list of dataset

Tags: dataframe, list, left-join

I am trying to do left_join to a datframe taking information from a object of class list that consit in 600 dataframe of GPS location with temeprature along 10 yeas for every hours.
The dataset where I what to attach the infromation is of this structure
[image]

in each location GPS I have a key that is the paste between GPS and day for 60 consecutive dates.
I want populate the first dataset with temeprature according key1, key2 etc from  a class list object that contain 600 dataframe like this:
[image]

there is a way to left_join between these two informations?
thank you very much in advance!
VL

PS: the two object are of these classes
the

> class(giornibirt)
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC8xI.png) "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

> class(l.df)
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC8xI.png) "list"

Comment: What database engine are you working on? It helps to tag the question with the relevant database technology.